# ConstraintLayout and AdMob AdView layout issue

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm using the following layout to have my content layout on top of the adview. The adview is supposed to be positioned to the bottom of screen. The adview height is `wrap_content`. The `top_view_layout` should span the rest of the screen. However, one user sent a screenshot with the adview taking HALF of the screen (the adview actually was blank in the user's screenshot so I suspect the ads was either not showing up or blocked). How is that possible with this layout?

Here is the layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_view_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_view_layout"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Update**: the user confirmed he had ad blocker enabled. The layout showed up fine after turning off the ad blocker. Apparently, the ad blocker is changing the AdView layout height form `wrap_content` to `0dp` so the AdView occupies half screen. However, is there a way to workaround that even when the ad blocker is on?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

This is a layout-ing error in your ConstraintLayout with a simple solution, Just remove the below line:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_view_layout"
```

from `AdView` and your error will be solved.

**Why?** By setting top to bottom of `top layout` and bottom to top of `AdView`, your are literally chaining them together to have equal `height` of the screen. Hence, the error.

Try it and update here if any other issues.

Comment: This works if the AdView's height is still wrap_content. However, with the ad blocker enabled the height is changed to 0dp so this won't work. The AdView won't show up at all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why don't you wrap your AdView in another Layout and then constraint it, so that even if Ad is blocked the AdView will be shown.